# What do you call a pair of diagonally-opposite points on a square or rectangle, relative to the other pair of points?

Tags: synonyms, mathematics, terminology

Suppose there is a rectangle with corners `N,E,S,W`, names assigned in a clockwise fashion, as you might expect. `N` and `S` are diametrically opposite, as are `E` and `W`.

[image]

Is there a term that describes points `E,W`, relative to `N,S`?

[I am told](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30416293#30416293) **diametrically opposite** is not totally correct, **perpendicular** describes *the line connecting the points* rather than the pairs of points themselves, and **other diagonally-opposite pair** is clumsy and dissatisfying. [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279317/how-to-name-the-diagonals-of-a-square-so-one-can-be-told-from-the-other) is related, but I'm hoping for a term which may be applied arbitrarily (without knowing the orientation of the rectangle, needed for *diagonal sinister* and *dexter*) and without referring directly to the cardinal points ("NS-EW," *etc.*).

Mathematics, like medicine, has nomenclature for every trivial thing (usually in Latin). Surely there must be a term for this, too?

(For clarity's sake, I am looking for a term describing the relationship between the *two pairs of points*, rather than between the individual points in the remaining pair.)

Comment: What's wrong with *opposite*?

Comment: @Silenus *Opposite* is okay, but the problem with it is that the term is more at home describing the points themselves, rather than the relationship between the two pairs of diagonally-opposite points.
That the points (collectively or individually) are not properly opposite from either in the other pair is a problem for it, as well. :/

Comment: I would say they're *opposite corners*.

Comment: What about *catercorner*?

Comment: @BruceWayne It looks like *[catercorner](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/catercorner?s=t)* also refers to the relationship between the remaining points ("diagonal"), rather than the relationship between the two pairs of points. I've never heard the term before, so I could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider **main** and **[transverse](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/transverse?s=t)** pairs: the 'transverse' pair lying *across* the diagonal axis described by the 'main' pair.
In geometry, 'transverse' seems to apply more to curves and waves than to points on a plane, though, so it may not be fully appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is any such term.  All I recall from my mathematics days (up through and including college—I'm now a Computer Scientist, we do no real math :-) ) is labeling each vertex A, B, C, and D, for instance.

This [Wolfram page on quadrilaterals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quadrilateral.html) gives a bunch of useful mathematics jargon terms.  The two diagonals, specifically, are the *polygon diagonals*.  You could speak of the "vertices of a polygon diagonal" and then simply say "the other vertices" or "the vertices of the other diagonal" to refer to either pair.

(Note that a rectangle is simply a special case of a parallelogram, which is a special case of a quadrilateral.  That, plus one Wolfram link, is hardly *proof* that there is no special term, of course.)

Comment: I'm an amateur programmer and city planner. What I know of math I know from ['Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). ;)
(And first year calculus which passed by the atoms of my fingernails, but eh.)

Answer (score 0):

The pairs are **symmetric** to each other.

That's the type of [rotational symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_symmetry).

Comment: That's true for remaining *points* relative to *each other,* but does it describe the pair properly? The two of them together are not symmetrically opposite from the first two. Also, this doesn't work on a rectangle...

Comment: There are different types of [symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry)

Comment: Aa, I see. It does have rotational symmetry. But does it describe one pair's relationship to the other, or the relationship between the remaining two points themselves?

Comment: The edit (1) removed '*A "normal" car*' which looked strange = improvement, (2) changed wording staying within OP's intention. Result: improvement. Edit accepted.

Comment: @Rathony In short: I uphold my decision to accept this edit. You can call me a moron, because I have different opinion than yours; but don't rebuke me for a lack of attention.

Comment: @Rathony Read my previous comment as a response to your last comment.

Comment: @Rathony (1) Because it does and got changed anyway; (2) Because the first sentence by OP reads: "Is there a word for the opposite of a driverless car?" If you compare the string "driverless car" in OP's sentence with a string "driverless car" in suggested edit, you will notice they are the same => the edit does not conflict with OP's intention. I already wrote it once. I see no point in continuing discussion with you. Your ongoing comments suggest you are incapable of accepting that another human might have a different opinion than yours. I hope it's just a lack of communication skills.